# do we say 'repairs on vehicle' or repairs of vehicle'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

what is the best way to say 'repairs on vehicle' or 'repairs of vehicle'
Because i get confused on how to use it whiles others use it the other way round

Answer (score 3):

I would say "repairs on a vehicle" or "repairs to a vehicle".

But using the singular (uncountable) form I would use "of": "repair of a vehicle".

I can't find any consistent difference in meaning between these forms ("repairs on", "repairs to" and "repair of": for me, they are in free variation.

Comment: In most contexts, ***vehicle repairs*** would probably be more likely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes. I was thinking that "[a] vehicle" represented a specific vehicle, eg "my car".

Comment: Checking NGrams for [singular ***repair*** with all permutations of ***of/to/on*** and ***a/the** vehicle*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repair+of+the+vehicle%2Crepair+of+a+vehicle%2Crepair+to+the+vehicle%2Crepair+to+a+vehicle%2Crepair+on+the+vehicle%2Crepair+on+a+vehicle&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepair%20of%20the%20vehicle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepair%20of%20a%20vehicle%3B%2Cc0) definitely confirms your point though. Only ***of*** occurs often enough to even figure on the chart, so +1 for that observation.

Comment: I can't believe two natives speakers are even arguing about this. The topic noun would vehicle repairs, and the rest depends on context, as Colin has basically said. Car repairs are a pain and very expensive, very often. Naturally, I don't go round talking about vehicle repairs in my everyday conversations. But I would in an SEO article.